# What is the name of the opposite of a convex cone?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, convex-cone

A subset $C$ of a vector space is a *cone* if for any element $x$ of $C$ and for any non-negative scalar $\alpha$, $ \alpha x\in C$.

Let $C$ be a cone.

When the sum of any two elements of $C$ is also in $C$, then the cone is said to be *convex*

I say $C$ is "the opposite of a convex cone" if the sum of any two linearly independent vectors of $C$ is outside of $C$. For example, a right circular cone (as a surface) is just that. Is there a standard name for this?

Comment: I suspect that such a set would have to be a finite collection of rays, so there is no point to having a special name for them. In 2D, for example, of any five rays at least one is a sum of two others, so you can have at most four.

Comment: @Conifold Sorry, I don't undersand. What's wrong in 3D with a right circular cone?

Comment: Take two vectors on the opposite sides of this cone and add them. The result belongs to it.

Comment: @Conifold I'm afraid this is a misunderstanding. By cone I mean a surface, not a body.

Comment: Rays that are not sums of other rays are called extreme, so the cones you want would have to consist of extreme rays exclusively, see [Mitchell, Extreme Points and Extreme Rays](http://homepages.rpi.edu/~mitchj/handouts/extreme97/extreme.html). But I was wrong, there can be infinitely many of them, in the (surface) circular cone each ray is extreme. I suppose you could call them cones of extreme rays, but I haven't seen anybody use such a name.